# $ is not defined when sending data with ReactJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm tryin to send data from a ReactJS form to PHP:

```
handleSubmit(event){
    $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: 'Register.php',
                  data: $('form').serialize(),
                  success: function () {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                  }
                });
            });
        });
}
```

I got this error message

> '$' is not defined

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The error usually indicate that the JavaScript file hasn't been loaded or you are calling the JavaScript code before it has been processed by the JS engine.

Answer (score 1):

I install JQuery with npm

```
npm install jQuery --save
```

then I add jQuery componement to my app

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

And finally it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your jquery file is in front of the reactjs file。or you can try:

```
$ npm i jquery
```

then import it

```
$ import $ from 'jquery'
```

Comment: OP already answered their question... and over 5 hours ago... Not sure why you're submitting the exact same answer.